# Meaning of "equality of functions as map germs along a curve"

Tags: differential-geometry, germs

I am trying to understand a notion given in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.07166) paper, summarized as the following:

> Let $c \colon I \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a smooth, regular, arc-length parametrized curve with image $C$, where $I$ is a compact interval of length $a$. 
> For a smooth function $\xi\colon I \to \mathbb{R}^3$ with $\xi(t) \times c'(t) \neq 0$ for all $t \in I$, we call
> $$f \colon I \times (- \varepsilon, \varepsilon) \to \mathbb{R}^3, (t,v) \mapsto c(t) + v \xi(t)   $$
> a ruled strip, where $\varepsilon > 0$ is fixed and chosen, such that $f$ is an embedding.
> Two ruled strips $f$ and $g$ along a curve $C$ are said to have the same image (**as map germs along $C$**), if there exists $\delta \in (0, \varepsilon]$, such that
> $$f(I \times (- \delta,\delta) ) \subseteq g(I \times (- \varepsilon,\varepsilon) ) $$
> holds.

I am a bit confused by this, because I only know of the definition of a germ based at a point, so I don't understand what a "map germ along $C$" is supposed to mean. In the paper, it also often done to call ruled strips "equal as map germs" without mentioning a base point like in the definition of a germ (which I think should mean again along $C$ in this case).
The only thing I could come up with while reading the paper are the following two interpretations of mine:

1. Map germs along $C$ means they are equal as germs at every point "along" $C$, i.e. we have $f,g$ are equal as germs at every point $(t,0)$ for $t \in I$.
2. Having the same image as map germs and being equal as map germs means the same thing, as a way of abbreviating wording.

Can anyone confirm this or give a proper definition? Is there in general maybe a notion of saying that two functions are germs at a given set?

Comment: The definition is super weird, its not even symmetric.

Comment: I think the idea is just that we want to give a local characterization of having the same image, related to the introduction of the germ notion I don't understand. Note that in the paper, there is an equivalent characterization for this property, yielding that it really is symmetrical.